# After Java migration from 1.6 to 1.7 I get a compilation error because of SocketChannel

Tags: java, maven, java-7, java-6, socketchannel

I have a maven project. I just migrated java from 1.6 to 1.7. The problem is that i cannot build the project. The compilation error is this:

```
[ERROR]\userdata\vlasopou\Desktop\fma_branch\flexi-web\src\test\java\com\nsn\mme\flexi\fm\fma\communication\TcpChannelTest.java:[39,58] error: <anonymous com.nsn.mme.flexi.fm.fma.communication.TcpChannelTest$1> is not abstract and does not override abstract method getRemoteAddress() in SocketChannel.
```

What is the root cause of this issue?

Comment: You have to override `getRemoteAddress()` in `TcpChannelTest$1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getRemoteAddress()` is a new method added to the interface `SocketChannel`. Implement it in your implementation of the interface and the error will be gone.